# UWSGI not receiving custom headers from nginx server

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

The goal is for `nginx` server to pass a custom request header called `X-PA-AUTH_TOKEN` to the `uwsgi` server. Below is the `server` block in `nginx.conf` file.

```
server {
    listen       9390 default_server;
    server_name  _;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass_request_headers      on;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/irm.sock;
            uwsgi_pass_header X-PA-AUTH_TOKEN;

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            #
            # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,X-PA-AUTH_TOKEN';
            #
            # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            add_header 'X-PA-AUTH_TOKEN' '0';
            return 204;
         }
         if ($request_method = 'POST') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,X-PA-AUTH_TOKEN';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range,X-PA-AUTH_TOKEN';
         }
         if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,X-PA-AUTH_TOKEN';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range,X-PA-AUTH_TOKEN';
         }
    }
}
```

The `uwsgi` server receives the conventional headers like 'Content-Type' just fine from the `nginx` server.

But, the `uwsgi` server is still not receiving the custom request header `X-PA-AUTH_TOKEN` from the `nginx` server when, for example, a POST request is made.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

I believe by default nginx marks headers with underscores (`X-PA-AUTH_TOKEN`) as invalid so they get blocked. You can either enable `underscores_in_headers: on;` in nginx config ([docs here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers)) or simply rename your header to be `X-PA-AUTH-TOKEN`.

Note however that if you enable `underscores_in_headers`, what you actually receive on the flask side will be renamed to `X-Pa-Auth-Token`, so i guess it's better to simply rename the header in the first place and not bother with nginx setting.